# Remove character - from string in java

Tags: java

I have this string 750410-7809 and want to remove "-" from the string, i.e. I want the string to be 7504107809.
I know I can use replace but it seems I get the wrong characters replaces. Please anyone help?

Comment: Please add your non-working code to your question, with the inputs, the result you expect and the result you're getting instead, so we can start from there. If in doubt please read about [example]s.

Comment: `replace` works as expected: https://ideone.com/jb6G84 (so it is not the problem, must be something else in your code, but we need to see it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.out.println("750410-7809".replace("-", ""))` seems to work fine.

Taking some guesses as to why it's 'not working' for you:

- You are using `replaceAll`. You want `replace`. `replace` replaces all instances; `replaceAll` also does so, but interprets the first argument as a regular expression pattern which you do not want.
- You are assuming strings are mutable:

```
String x = "1234-5678";
x.replace("-", ""); // this does nothing
System.out.println(x); // prints 1234-5678
```

Strings cannot be modified; instead, `replace` creates a new string and returns it. Make that `x = x.replace("-", "")` and the above works fine.

- There isn't a dash in your string, but some other dash-like character. There are **a lot** of characters in the unicode table that look like a dash. Trivially, here is a dash: - and here is an mdash: – can you tell the difference, just looking at it? The mdash is slightly larger. It's a different character: `System.out.println("1234–5678".replace("-", ""))` prints `1234-5678` because that's an mdash in the string and an ndash (a 'normal' one) in the replace string. Inspect each character, e.g. by printing its value with `System.out.println((int) str.charAt(4))` for example.

Answer (score 1):

```
  String original_string = "750410-7809";
  original_string = original_string.replace("-", "");
  System.out.println(original_string);
```